# Reference request: modern reference for Cantor's theorems of size of algebraic and transcendental numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

Cantor showed that the set of algebraic numbers is countable and the set of transcendental numbers is uncountable. Is there any (modern)book with the proof of these theorems?

Comment: Hopefully, someone will just post the proof. Its pretty straightforward.

Comment: As far as the reference request goes, it appears in most any text that discusses cardinality. Frequently as an exercise. It's in baby Rudin as an exercise, as I recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that there are only countably many algebraic numbers appears as a theorem in *Mathematical Analysis I* by Zorich. Then the existence of transcendental numbers is stated as a corollary of the theorem that $\mathbf{R}$ is uncountable.

The fact that the set of transcendental numbers has the cardinality of the continuum is only an exercise there.

However, the fact that there are uncountably many transcendental numbers is a direct consequence of the facts I mentioned that appear as theorems together with the theorem that the union of two countable sets is also countable.